# How many bit strings of length n contain exactly r 1s?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

[image]

This has me confused. Wouldn't we want to use permutations in this case, and not combinations, since order is relevant when forming bit strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $n$ digits, what we want to decide is which of these digits are going to be 1. Since there are $r$ 1's we have to select the $r$ digits that are going to be $1$ out of the $n$ digits. We can do this in $\binom{n}{r}$ ways.

The reason why order doesn't matter is in the sense that all digits $1$ are going to be the same.

Comment: Okay. But still, isn't this a task asking us to construct a $n$ bit string with exactly $r$ $1$s. The task has two steps pick the $1$s than pick the $0$s so wouldn't it be $\binom{n}{r}$ * $\binom{n}{n-r}$(how we pick the $0$s)? By rule of product?

Comment: since all the digits are either $1$ or $0$ once you know where the $1$'s go you can be certain wehere the zeroes go (the ones that are still empty)

Comment: Okay. So the way I'm thinking of it right now is: Imagine we have $n$ spaces $n_1,n_2,n_3,...,n_n$ what you're doing is saying, lets select r of these spaces for the 1s in the bit string, and all the leftover spaces are for the $0$s. Am I getting this right?

Comment: yes, that is precisely how it works.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $n=10, r=3$.  If you used permutations, then selecting the first, second, and third bits (to be 1 instead of 0) is one possible choice.  Selecting the third, second, and first bits is a different one.  But you don't want to count these differently, you want to count these the same.  Using combinations, selecting $\{1,2,3\}$ is one way of choosing three positions, and $\{1,3,8\}$ is another one.

Comment: Great example. It is all about selecting some positions among all possible positions to place 1s. Your explanation helped me to understand that after two days.